# Why can't the Schwarzschild radius be larger than the Compton wavelength?

Tags: quantum-gravity, information

In the second paragraph of the third page of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00747), the author makes a statement

> The dynamical process must now involve, not the length scale $R_{s}$, but rather the universal length $L_{CS}$. An evaporating black hole, which rolls down the right half of the curve $(z > 0)$ by losing mass via Hawking radiation, must settle down at the minimum length $2L_{Pl}$, which is at $m=m_{Pl}/2$. **It cannot rise up to the left side of the curve and emit radiation, which would require $R_{S} > λ_{C}$.**

I don't understand why shouldn't it be in general case. If someone can explain this, it would be great.